# Query for returning duplicate values

Tags: mysql, duplicates

**database**

```
id   name
1    suhana
2    nishantini
3    suhana
4    deepa
5    suhana
```

how to write a query in the field name [name] to get an output

```
id name
1  suhana
3  suhana
5  suhana
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id, name from table_name where name in (SELECT name FROM table_name group by name having count(name) > 1)
```